# BlinkID Plugin Error Ionic 4 - Native: tried calling BlinkId.BarcodeRecognizer, but the BlinkId plugin is not installed

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework, ionic4, blinkid

I have an Ionic 4 cordova project which I want to integrate the MicroBlink [BlinkID Plugin](https://microblink.com/products/pdf417/mobile-sdk) to scan PDF417 barcodes. I installed the BlinkID Plugin following instructions from the [Ionic website](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/blinkid) and added the snippet to scan barcodes. However I get an error on the line where we call the BarcodeRecognizer function.

```
const barcodeRecognizer = new this.blinkId.BarcodeRecognizer();
barcodeRecognizer.scanPdf417 = true;
```

The error from XCode console is;
WARN: Native: tried calling BlinkId.BarcodeRecognizer, but the BlinkId plugin is not installed.
WARN: Install the BlinkId plugin: 'ionic cordova plugin add blinkid-cordova’

Can anyone please assist.

Answer (score 2):

The public version of BlinkID (which can be found on GitHub), does not contain the BarcodeRecognizer.

The official GitHub page to BlinkID Cordova: https://github.com/BlinkID/blinkid-cordova

However, there is a version of BlinkID that contains all of the recognizers, including the BarcodeRecognizer.

In order to acquire it, you will need to contact the support team at support@microblink.com and they will enabled you the right for the Custom SDK with all of the recognizers.

Hope this helps.
Milan